# jQuery .each() only applying to last element

Tags: jquery, each

I've seen lots of answers to similar questions, but can't seem to get this figured out for my specific case.  My jQuery logic is only applying to the last element in my `.each()` function.  Can anyone help me understand why?  Ultimately, I'm trying to split the items in my lists into two columns.

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
</ul>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
</ul>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
</ul>
```

And here's my jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        var col1 = jQuery('<li class="col1">col1</li>'); // object which I will append the list items into
        var col2 = jQuery('<li class="col2">col2</li>'); // object which I will append the list items into

        jQuery('.sub-menu').each(function() {
            var items = jQuery(this).html(); // get original items from list
            jQuery(this).empty(); // clear original items from list

            jQuery(this).append(col1).append(col2); // just appending new columns for now, will add the original items to either col1 or col2 once this is working.
        });

});
</script>
```

My code properly captures the original list items and clears the current `.sub-menu` list, but then adding the columns into the list is only happening for the last element in the `.each()` loop.  In other words the two columns are only getting added to the last `.sub-menu` and the first two end up with no list items.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're describing is that you are appending the col1 and col2 to the first list, then appending the **same elements** to the second, and finally to the third.

You need to create new elements each time, or duplicate the originals.

Here's the updated code (I added `.clone()` where you append col1 and col2)
    var col1 = jQuery('col1'); // object which I will append the list items into
    var col2 = jQuery('col2'); // object which I will append the list items into

```
jQuery('.sub-menu').each(function() {
    var items = jQuery(this).html(); // get original items from list
    jQuery(this).empty(); // clear original items from list

    jQuery(this).append(col1.clone()).append(col2.clone()); // just appending new columns for now, will add the original items to either col1 or col2 once this is working.
        });​
```

Comment: Yeppers!  That's was it!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to find:

`var col1 = jQuery('<li class="col1">col1</li>');`

You can't find an object that doesn't exist yet. Simply remove the `jQuery` function, like this:

```
var col1 = '<li class="col1">col1</li>';
var col2 = '<li class="col2">col2</li>';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/frnYY/

Comment: "You can't find an object that doesn't exist yet",  actually this is not finding, this is creating a new li. The solution is explained by @Tom, although your solution is better :D